# Why a periodic solution of a autonomous system is never asymptotically stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot x=f(x)$ an ODE. In [this link](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Orbit_stability) (in the middle of the article) it's says that a periodic solution is never asymptotically stable. Can someone explain why ?  Because in my mind, I could imagine that a situation as in the following picture could arise, and this look asymptotically stable, no ? So if $x(t)$ is a solution that ly on the periodic orbit and if $y(t)$ is a solution that lies on the black orbit, I could imagine that $|x(t)-y(t)|\to 0$ when $t\to \infty $ (of course, we need that $y(t)$ is fact enough, but I guess it could happen... no ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that lies on a periodic trajectory, but slightly delays in relation to some fixed periodic solution, does not "tend" to it.

Let $x(t)=\phi (t)$, $\phi(t+T)=\phi(t)$ be a periodic solution 
of the initial value problem
$$\tag{1}
\dot x= f(x),\quad x(t_0)=x_0.
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be an arbitrarily small number. By virtue of continuity of $\phi(t)$, there exists a sufficiently small $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$
\|\phi(t_0+\delta)-\phi(t_0)\|<\epsilon.
$$
Now consider the initial value problem
$$\tag{2}
\dot x= f(x),\quad x(t_0-\delta)=x_0.
$$
Its solution is $\psi(t)=\phi(t+\delta)$ (notice that it is also periodic), hence 
$$
\|\psi(t_0)-\phi(t_0)\|=\|\phi(t_0+\delta)-\phi(t_0)\|<\epsilon.
$$ 
Asymptotic stability of $\phi(t)$ implies that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} \|\psi(t)-\phi(t)\|=0;
$$
but this is impossible because $\forall n\in\mathbb N$
$$
\|\psi(t_0+nT)-\phi(t_0+nT)\|=\|\psi(t_0)-\phi(t_0)\|,
$$
which is constant.

Comment: nice :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The periodic solution, if it is really a cycle, does obviously not converge towards a stationary point. Thus it is not asymptotically stable. But your link and your example are about *orbital* stability, which is a different concept, it is about convergence towards the periodic solution, which stands in place of the stationary point.

Comment: Why does an asymptotically stable solution should converges to a stationary point ? $x_t$ is a stable solution if for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $\forall \xi: \|x(t_0)-\xi\|<\delta \implies \lim_{t\to \infty }\|x(t)-\Phi^{t,t_0}(\xi)\|=0$. But $x(t)$ doesn't need to converges to a stationary point... does it ? Also, if $(x_t)$ is asymptotically stable, it's also orbitally stable (so no need to be periodic to be asymptotycally stable)... I'm sorry, but could you clarify a bit ?

Comment: Yes, the definition you gave is for a *stable* point. For an *aymptotically stable* point you get additionally the convergence to the stationary point.

Comment: Not really. Stable point (using my definition) is : $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0: \forall \xi, \|x(t_0)-\xi\|<\delta \implies \sup_{t\geq t_0}\|x(t)-\Phi^{t,t_0}(\xi)\|<\varepsilon $. There is no necessity of stationary point in those definition (if what you call stationary point is $\bar x$ s.t. $f(\bar x)=0$).