# Show that the unit circle is an exponentially stable limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system, limit-cycles

Consider the system:

$\dot{x_{1}}=x_{2}+x_{1}(1-x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}^{2})$

$\dot{x_{2}}=-x_{1}+x_{2}(1-x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}^{2})$

Transform the system into polar coordinates and use this to show that the unit circle is an exponentially stable limit cycle on $D=\left\{ x:x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\geq\epsilon>0\right\}$

I have done the transformation to polar coordinates with $x_{1}=rcos(\theta ) , x_{2}=rsin(\theta)$ and got the system:

$\dot{\theta}=-1$

$\dot{r}=r(1-r^{2})$

And now I am not sure how to proceed. Intuitively I would like to use a Poincare map and show that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}(r^{*})<1$ where $r^{*}=1$ but I don't know how to do it in practice or even if this is the correct approach.

edit:
as suggested solving the ODE yields

$P(r(0),\theta(0))=(\frac{e^{t}}{\sqrt{−1+r(0)−2+e^{2t}}},t+\theta(0))$

and for the strip $H:=\left\{ (r,\theta):r>0,\theta=2k\pi,k\in Z\right\}$  with return time to $H$, $ \tau(r(0),2\pi)=2\pi$

I eventually get:

$P(r(0))=\frac{e^{2π}}{\sqrt{−1+r(0)−2+e^{4π}}},r(0)\neq0⇒P(1)=1$

and $|\frac{\partial P}{\partial r(0)}(1)|=|e^{-4\pi}|<1$ but this only shows local asymptotic stability. I don't know what needs to be modified to make it show exponential stability on the aforementioned $D$

Comment: Just solve $r$ by separation of variables.

Comment: Analysis of Autonomous Equations could help. Not of $r$ is greater than 1, the derivative is negative and the derivative is 0 at r=1 and positive for $r<1$. That suggests stability at r=1. Though not the exact sort of stability yo are looking for, probably closely tied.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)

Comment: @LPZ I edited my question with your suggestion. But I'm still stuck on showing the exponential stability on $D$.

Comment: It should be noted that the question of assignment is not entirely correct. The limit cycle of an autonomous system cannot be asymptotically stable, much less exponentially stable (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278798/why-a-periodic-solution-of-a-autonomous-system-is-never-asymptotically-stable/). Here it would be correct to talk about orbital stability (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Orbit_stability).

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @AVK True but I think that from the context of the assignment it's clear that we talk about orbital stability. It's just that I couldn't find a way to show exponential orbital stability but just an asymptotic one.

Comment: There is no need to solve the differential equation and estimate the solution here. Instead, it is much easier to: 1. make the change of variables $z=r-1$ in the equation $\dot r=r(1-r^2)$; 2. select the Lyapunov function $V(z)=\frac12 z^2$; 3. apply the exponential stability theorem.